# Get Teaser component SXA style in Powershell script

Tags: sxa, powershell

I would like to get selected SXA style of the Teaser component in Powershell script.

I have a teaser component where i have selected SXA style on Experience editor . I would like to get selected SXA style  of that component in Powershell script. Is it possible ?

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this PowerShell script to find all the selected styles for any particular rendering. Enhance this script as per your requirements.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{B008740C-839F-40BF-B343-84E14F6AEDC4}"
$defaultLayout = Get-LayoutDevice "Default"
#Get the Teaser Rendering by passing Placeholder Name and Item ID
$rendering= Get-Rendering -Item $item -Placeholder "*/main/container-23/row-4-12*" -Device $defaultLayout -FinalLayout
# Assuming this returns one rendering only
$dict = [Sitecore.Web.WebUtil]::ParseQueryString($rendering.Parameters)
$parameterValue = $dict['Styles'].Replace("%7B","{").Replace("%7D","}").Replace("%7C","|").Split('|')
foreach($styleItem in $parameterValue)
{
    $itemname = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $styleItem
    write-host $itemname.Name
}
```

Comment: Could you assist me how can I use the same scenario for Slick Carousel as with above code it is not getting the selected style ?

Comment: This code should work for all rendering, just make sure you have given the right placeholder and put write-host to find out if the correct rendering is being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it simply by using the `Rendering Parameter` on the item.

Your script should be like this.

```
# Get your item by ID
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{B485F716-9E95-42E8-8DE0-844E988A1BDF}"

# Create a loop on all the renderings of the item. 
foreach($itemRendering in Get-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout) {
    # Get the rendering Parameters. 
    Get-RenderingParameter -Rendering $itemRendering | Format-Table -Auto
}
```

You will get the rendering parameters data with Style parameters also like this.

```
Name                  Value
----                  -----
Navigation            {848DFE42-2B13-430E-A0B9-89CE25730A06}
Transition            {D4B706CC-7EEC-4DB9-A87D-123B29803490}
Timeout               2000
PauseOnHover          1
Reset Caching Options
GridParameters        {908E2BC6-C110-4ED7-AF39-7EEACBB31A34}
Styles                {C414B189-DAA3-4490-9B03-A7B6F4AC3A2C}|{F2A30C96-BC00-4CCD-BC1E-384744EE24C8}|{32E7E96A-17CD-4FDE-90D8-62A48B0D8BF5}
RenderingIdentifier
DynamicPlaceholderId  3
```

You will get the `Styles` ID. Now update the above logic and use `Get-Item` to get the field values on this item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The documentation provides some good examples as well. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/presentation/get-renderingparameter#example-1

Comment: Slick Carousel this code is not working

Comment: @Nisha let me check. Are you using OOTB Carousel? And can you specify the Sitecore version?

Comment: @Nisha I tested that for the Carousel and it works. And the values that are coming in my answer are for the Carousel component.

Comment: I have added style on "Slick Carousel slide content" and it is showing nothing

Comment: Able to get style on Slick Carousel as well

Comment: @Nisha Great! So did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for ur response.

Comment: @Nisha Please accept the answer if you think it resolves your issue. Thanks